# Entropy and entropy decay

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the following exercise:
We consider the example of the two molecules $U_1$ reaction reversible to one molecule $U_2$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0\\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\begin{pmatrix} 
U_1 \\\ 
U_2
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1\\\ 
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\begin{pmatrix} 
U_1 \\\ 
U_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
If the substance $U_i$ (i=1,2) diffuse in $\Omega$ with constant diffusivities $d_i$
​ and the reaction rates are modelled by the mass action law and independent of temperature, we obtain the system

\begin{equation}
\partial _t u_1 - d_1 \Delta u_1=-2(u_1 ^2-u_2),\\\
\partial _t u_2 - d_2 \Delta u_2=u_1 ^2-u_2
\end{equation}

together with homogeneous Neumann conditions $n(x)\nabla _{x} u_i(t,x)=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and $n(x)$ denoting the unit outer normal of a bounded domain $\Omega$.
Calculate the entropy of given system and the corresponding entropy decay.

I am not really familiar with this topic. Hence, I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not.
I did the following:
I defined the entropy as
\begin{equation}
\epsilon (t)=\int_{\Omega} (-u_1 ln(u_1)-u_2 ln(2)) dx
\end{equation}
In order to analyze the entropy decay, I calculated the time derivative of $\epsilon$.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\epsilon}{dt}=-\int(\partial _t u_1 ln(u_1)+\partial _t u_2 ln(u_2))
\end{equation}
Then, I substituted the given system equations
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\epsilon}{dt}=\int(d_1\Delta u_1 ln(u_1)+d_2\Delta u_2 ln(u_2))+2(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_1)+(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_2))dx.
\end{equation}
Next I used the Neumann boundary conditions and integration by parts
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\epsilon}{dt}=\int(-d_1\nabla (u_1  \nabla  ln(u_1))-d_2 \nabla (u_2  \nabla  ln(u_2))+2(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_1)+(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_2))dx.
\end{equation}
After that I used the divergence theorem for the first two terms
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\epsilon}{dt}=-\int_{\Omega}(2(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_1)+(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_2))dx-\int_{\partial\Omega} (d_1 u_1\nabla (ln(u_1)).n+d_2 u_2  \nabla  ln(u_2).n )ds 
\end{equation}
Finally, I got the following expression
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\epsilon}{dt}=-\int_{\Omega}[2(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_1)+(u_1 ^2-u_2)ln(u_2)]dx
\end{equation}

Is my solution correct or are there any mistakes?
Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your answer. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Could you specify in which term? I never computed the derivative directly but substituted the equations which are given in the system.

Comment: Okay thank you! Could you tell me whether my approach is correct or not? And would my solution be correct if I replaced ln(u) by ln(u)+1?